# How to use multiple Java annotations with the same value?

Tags: java, firebase, annotations, gson, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit along with GSON to retrieve data from an API and deserialize it to Java objects using GSON's `@SerializedName` annotation like below:

```
public class MyApiObject {
    @SerializedName("apiJsonKey")
    private String myValue;
    ...
}
```

It works fine, but I need to send objects of `MyApiObject` to a Firebase database and for that the object needs to be serialized back to JSON. Firebase's Java API does this automatically, but it generates the keys based on the instance variable's names (`myValue`) and not the serialized name (`"apiJsonKey"`).

I know I can use Firebase's `@PropertyName` annotation, but that would require me to use two annotations with the same values, which is redundant and error-prone.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The usual aproach in this cases is to set a constant and use it in both annotations.

```
public class MyApiObject {
    private static final String MY_VALUE_NAME = "apiJsonKey";

    @SerializedName(MY_VALUE_NAME)
    @ParameterName(MY_VALUE_NAME)
    private String myValue;
    ...
}
```

This is fairly usual in sequence annotations for JPA.

Comment: I did think about this approach, but my class has over a dozen such parameters/instance variables, each of which would require a separate constant String. It just seems unnecessary, is that really the best way to go?

Comment: Then maybe your class represents too many things. When you end up with big classes it usually means they could be broke up in smaller classes that work together. Even if your case doesn't fit to multiple classes I think is better to not introduce error prone-code, even if it is bigger, and as you said, using the same string repeatedly is a bad idea.

Comment: Another option is to have a class of constants separated. But usually classes and packages with names like Constants, common, utils, etc end up being a hole for code that you don't know where to put. I think it's better to spend more time defining, redefining and refining your classes. It takes too long, but you usually end up with a stronger design, more readable and mantainable.